# How to make my layout to move completely left of screen like an animation in android?

Tags: android

I have a Relative Layout in my xml,I want to move that view to complete left like an animation(upto screen left). I want the complete inner layout to move like an animation upto screen end

I want to put animation for Relative layout with id="center"

```
 <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:background="@drawable/img_1"

     android:layout_centerInParent="true"  

    android:id="@+id/cartoon_image"> 

  <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/play_btn"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:id="@+id/play_btn"
       >
       <RelativeLayout
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="vertical"
     android:visibility="gone"

       android:gravity="center"
       android:background="@drawable/circle"
      android:id="@+id/center">


  <ImageView 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/like_small"
        android:id="@+id/like_image_centre"

       />  

  <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/like_image_centre"
        android:text="36"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:textColor="#DF013A"
        android:id="@+id/likes_count_centre"

        />

 </RelativeLayout>
       </RelativeLayout>
  </RelativeLayout>
```

Please help in solving this issue

Answer (score 3):

try this code  in onCreate of your activity

by changing this function`TranslateAnimation(fromX,toX,fromY,toY)` ,you can set the Animation you want to move the layout.

```
RelativeLayout mLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.layout.center);


    TranslateAnimation anim=new TranslateAnimation(0,80,0,0);
            anim.setDuration(1500);
            anim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
         // anim.setRepeatMode(Animation.INFINITE);
            anim.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);

            mLayout.setAnimation(anim);
```

Comment: put the corresponding id of the layout you want to animate

Comment: and increase the toX position to greater to move long.

Comment: But my layout is centre to its parent so animation is going background